# How to connect a Desktop (without WiFi) with a Laptop (with WiFi card)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I recently bought a Dell laptop. I have a very old desktop system with no WiFi. My WiFi router is connected to the desktop using a cable (Ethernet?). I connect to the net via WiFi router (for the laptop). Now I want to share files between these two systems.

Is that possible?

Both systems run on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as one of the computers is not Windows 7 Starter nor Windows 7 Home Basic then you can create a Homegroup and share files/printers

[HomeGroup from start to finish](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/homegroup-from-start-to-finish)

Comment: You don't necessarily need a Homegroup to accomplish this though.

Comment: No you are right, but Homegroups are suppose to be the simple easier secure way... isn't it :)

Comment: Supposedly, yes.

Comment: Woohoo! I can now share files between the systems. It was easier than I expected!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Though one machine connects to the router via cable and the other wirelessly, both machines are part of the same local network (assuming you haven't changed the router's settings to something weird). You can thus share files between computers the same way as in an all-wireless or all-wired network: see [Microsoft's documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Share-files-with-someone) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, just make sure you have **File and printer sharing** enabled. As well as **Network descovery**. As shown here:

[image: Network]